# PowerShell - Temp File Checking - If Then - Run Commands

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and trying to do some basic "Create Temp File" "Check if Temp File Exists" "If FileExists = True/False Then" coding logic and I'm clearly missing something as I'm not getting consistent results.

Here is what I have so far, and the issue seems to be that `$TmpFileExists` isn't being updated when "re-run" (is it being re-run?)

I expect the second run of the IF statement to return the ELSE portion, but it just returns "TRUE".

```
$TmpFile = New-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\jobrunning.log" -ItemType File
$TmpFileExists = (Test-Path $TmpFile) | Out-String
$DelTmpFile = Remove-Item $TmpFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
IF ($TmpFileExists  = "True") {$DelTmpFile ; $TmpFileExists } ELSE {Write-Host "File NOT Found"}
IF ($TmpFileExists  = "True") {$DelTmpFile ; $TmpFileExists } ELSE {Write-Host "File NOT Found"}
```

The idea is, if it finds the file, delete it, reset/check the boolean `TmpFileExists` and re-run the If statement should now return `ELSE/FALSE` statement.

Comment: should `Test-Path $TmpFile` be `Test-Path $TmpFile.FullName` as an example? It's not totally clear what's going on but that might help get you going.

Comment: It's not clear why you are creating a file to delete it.  Is it to check you have the ability to write to the temp location?  Here is some similar code that you might be able to use? https://pastebin.com/J3aRwZfM

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong.  For example `$TmpFileExists  = "True"` here you are assigning a string "True" to the $TmpFileExists variable not checking if it's True. Usually you just say `if (test-path "a.txt"){"exists"}else{"not exist"}"` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking it line-by-line:

```
$TmpFile = New-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\jobrunning.log" -ItemType File
```

So far, so good. You've created your file.

```
$TmpFileExists = (Test-Path $TmpFile) | Out-String
```

$TmpFileExists now has a string value of "True" *that will not change without re-assignment or other manipulation*. Referencing a variable does not re-evaluate its assignment expression. You should place `Test-Path` inline or define a function.

```
$DelTmpFile = Remove-Item $TmpFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

You have now deleted the file referenced by `$TmpFile`. Your subsequent code seems to assume it's a simple function. The varialbe `$DelTmpFile` has a value of `$Null`.

```
IF ($TmpFileExists  = "True") {$DelTmpFile ; $TmpFileExists } ELSE {Write-Host "File NOT Found"}
IF ($TmpFileExists  = "True") {$DelTmpFile ; $TmpFileExists } ELSE {Write-Host "File NOT Found"}
```

These expressions, as HelpingHand noted, are re-assisgning the string value of "Ttue". Any sucessful non-null assignment expression will evaluate to `$True` when cast as a Boolean. So translating, these expressions reduce to:

```
If ($True) { $Null; "True"} Else {Write-Host "File NOT Found"}
```

Making it (hopefully) obvious why your `Else` clause never executes.

---

Working sample:

```
$TmpFile = New-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\jobrunning.log" -ItemType File
### File has been created
If ( Test-Path $TmpFile ) {
    Write-Host "File found. Deleting..."
    Remove-Item $TmpFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} Else {
    Write-Host "File NOT Found"
}
### File now deleted
If ( Test-Path $TmpFile ) {
    Remove-Item $TmpFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} Else {
    Write-Host "File NOT Found"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for this answer! "Referencing a variable does not re-evaluate its assignment expression. You should place Test-Path inline or define a function." This line explains how my answer came to me intuitively, but really I was just "throwing spaghetti at the wall" vs understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Keith Miller's Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1579755/465645) explained I was trying to reference a variable expecting it to "re-evaluate". I decided intuitevly to use functions and got everything working. Here is what I ended up with, but it's not 100% the same, as there I didn't build a "If Else" "Delete File" snippet, but It was mostly a learning exercise and I'm confident in my understanding now.

```
$FilePath="$env:TEMP\jobrunning.log"

#Del File if Exists and Test
Remove-File -FilePath $FilePath
$FExistBool = Test-DoesFileExistBool -FilePath $FilePath
Compare-IsBoolTrue -FilePath $FilePath -TFBool $FExistBool

#Create File And Re-Try
Add-EmptyFile -FilePath $FilePath
$FExistBool = Test-DoesFileExistBool -FilePath $FilePath
Compare-IsBoolTrue -FilePath $FilePath -TFBool $FExistBool

#Del File and Re-Try
Remove-File -FilePath $FilePath
$FExistBool = Test-DoesFileExistBool -FilePath $FilePath
Compare-IsBoolTrue -FilePath $FilePath -TFBool $FExistBool

#Last Run
Add-EmptyFile -FilePath $FilePath
$FExistBool = Test-DoesFileExistBool -FilePath $FilePath
Compare-IsBoolTrue -TFBool $FExistBool

##End Script##
PAUSE
##Funcs#
function Compare-IsBoolTrue {
    param (
        [string[]]$TFBool
    )
    IF ($TFBool -eq "True") {
     Write-Host "File Found"
    } ELSE {
     Write-Host "File NOT Found"
    }
}
function Test-DoesFileExistBool {
    param (
        [string[]]$FilePath
    )
    Test-Path $FilePath 2> $null
}

function Remove-File {
    param (
        [string[]]$FilePath
    )
    Remove-Item $FilePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

function Add-EmptyFile {
    param (
        [string[]]$FilePath
    )
    New-Item -Path $FilePath -ItemType File 2>&1>$null
}
```

**Result:**

```
File NOT Found
File Found
File NOT Found
File Found
Press Enter to continue...:
```

Comment: Your code may have worked after you copied it into PowerShell a second time OR run it a second time in ISE, but not at its first time, as you have to define your functions before you use them. Besides that, I recommend to you the [`New-TemporaryFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-temporaryfile?view=powershell-7) cmdlet. With that, you don't have to care about possible duplicate filenames, as it will generate a random name for you.

Comment: ISE will run it in the first "paste" I'm fairly certain, but I quickly realized I had to put my functions are the top (which I don't like, but thats what it is) for it to work in a `.ps1`. As well, I purposefully didn't use `New-TemporaryFile` as I only use Temp Files for things that are "hacky" (generally a placeholder/flag for a process check between two apps that don't communicate) and therefor I need to KNOW the name, not have a `random name` generated for me. Useful tips non the less, thank you.